# Javascript error in every browser except Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cross-browser

I'm pulling my hair out over this. I have this bit of javascript that asynchronously fetches data for an events calendar. Basically when you click on a day of the month a little UI pops up and a text area gets populated with the data that gets retrieved. On this UI are two submit buttons: one to save changes, and one to delete the event if it exists. My goal is to have the delete button disabled unless the text area gets populated with an event. Here is my code:

```
function editDialog(date,vis)
{
    if(vis == "show")
    {
        var event="Loading...";

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        { 
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                event = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            document.getElementById('editwrapper').innerHTML="<div id='editdiv'>\
            <div><span class='bold'>"+date+" </span><div style='display: inline; float: right;'><a href='#' onclick=\"return editDialog('"+date+"','hide')\">Close</a></div><hr id='line'> \
            <form method='get' action='' onsubmit=\"return editDialog(this.newdate.value, 'show')\">\
            <label for='newdate'>Jump to: </label>\
            <input type='text' name='newdate' size='10'/>\
            <input type='submit' name='go' value='Go'>\
            </form>\
            <form style='display: inline;' action='' name='saveform' method='get' onsubmit='return instantUpdate(this.date.value,this.event.value)'>\
            <textarea name='event' rows='10' cols='40' onkeypress='saveform.edit.disabled=false'>"+event+"</textarea>\
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='"+date+"'>\
            <input type='submit' name='edit' value='Save' disabled='disabled'></form> &nbsp; <form name='deleteform' style='display: inline; float: right;' action='' method='get' onsubmit=\"return instantUpdate(saveform.date.value,'')\"> <input name='deletebutton' value='Delete' type='submit'></form>\
            </div>\
            </div>";

            if(event=="" || event=="Loading...") document.deleteform.delete.disabled = true;
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","events.php?action=read&date="+date,true);
        xmlhttp.send(); } }
```

The problem lies with this statement:

```
if(event=="" || event=="Loading...") document.deleteform.deletebutton.disabled = true;
```

Firefox handles it just fine but Safari, Chrome, Opera, and IE all throw hissy fits. They revert back to my fallback functionality for users that don't have javascript enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did Chromes debugger say?

Comment: I actually didn't look. But I'm not very familiar with how to use it. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Ahh yes, jQuery. I would love to use it but I want to actually learn javascript properly first...

Comment: @vince88: Jquery is javascript. It's just a framework. Use it. It's really worth it.

Comment: No I understand what jquery is. But I want to learn what goes on behind the scenes rather than have everything masked by easy to use functions. What if I take on a project that doesn't implement jQuery?

Comment: @vince88 if you don't fix the multi-line strings, it's not going to work for you in IE.

Comment: @pointy I really hate IE7. Thanks for the info. I've made the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a thought. Since `delete` is a keyword you really shouldn't be using it as a form field name. Some implementations may be more strict than others with regard to using reserved words. Try renaming it to something else.

Comment: Yes, this it. I took the advice from one of the comments and looked at Chrome's debugger. It says that delete was throwing an exception so I renamed it and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: @vince - Good luck, and don't forget to try out jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-line string constants are non-standard. You can't do that in other browsers.

Long strings have to look like this:

```
var longString = "something something something" +
  "more something something something " +
  "and so on";
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll keep it in mind but I don't think that's the trouble here. I changed it up and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Line continuations where added to the ECMAScript standard in version 5 so it will be a while before all browsers support it.

Comment: Yes I know it's in v. 5 but that won't help you in IE7 :-)